# Editing MS SQL DB with 20 tables to 1 table without data lost

Tags: sql-server, database

Hello I don't know how to do changes of my `MS SQL  DB` to integrate it to work with new software.

The case is related with software limitations.

Our old software can write, read and work with MS SQL DB with multiple tables but the new software understand only from one table or one view table.

My question is how can I edit my MS SQL DB  form 20 tables to do it to be one DB with one table with all data from 20 tables and columns without data lost?

And one last question is true about View Tables in MS SQL that they are read only for applications and software?

Comment: I would reject any software that can only work with one table. It is just wrong

Comment: The new software is simply not compatible with your database. Ask yourself, what is more important. `your data` in your database or `new software` ? Which of these 2 you cant do without ? Any new software must be made to work with existing data, not the other way around

Comment: The software is IDFLOW.

DB and software both are important.

Software support MS SQL DB but with limitations like work with only one table or view table.

I am with permissions to customize the DB but how can I do it . 

To create new DB with one table from 20 tables from old DB to integrate it in new software, what is best practice ?

Comment: Small changes in a DB can be acceptable when new software is used. But putting all 20 tables into 1 table is just wrong. That would violate every rule of normalization, create huge redundancy, break referential integrity. And if that is not enough, I think you need at least one person that needs to correct the data whole day long, every day, to keep the redundant data up to date

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here, the new software is probably used to import/export data from your database to another. And that is indeed often done with just one table. If that is your case, you should create a view that offers the new software what it needs. But I really doubt you need all your 20 tables for that.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it not a good idea to put data from all your 20 tables into one table ?
I will try to explain with an example, since I do not know your database I just think of some tables here

suppose you have a table `Clients`

```
ClientID  Name  Street       City

    1     John  ChuchStreet  Denver
    2     Anna  FlowerStreet Boston
```

and a table `Products`

```
ProductID  Name     Price

   1       Mouse      10
   2       Keyboard   30
   3       Usb Cable  10
```

and table `Orders`

```
 OrderID  OrderNumber  CLientID  TotalAmount

    1        123          1         10
    2        345          1         20
    3        678          2         30
```

and finally table `OrderDetail`

```
 OrderDetailID  OrderID  ProductID  Quantity

       1          1         1          1
       2          2         1          1
       3          2         3          1
       4          3         2          1
```

Now to put this into one table, you could do this

```
  ID  ClientName  ClientStreet  ClientCity  OrderNumber  TotalAmount  ProductName  ProductPrice  ProductQuantity  

  1     John        ChurchStreet  Denver         123          10     Mouse           10             1
  1     John        ChurchStreet  Denver         345          20     Mouse           10             1
  2     John        ChurchStreet  Denver         345          20     Usb Cable       10             1
  3     Anna        FlowerStreet  Boston         678          30     Keyboard        30             1
```

Now you can already see the redundancy,
you need to repeat the address of each customer, time and time again in your table
you need to repeat the ordernumber and total amount time and time again
you need to repeat the productname and price time and time again

Now suppose that John moves to another address, now you have to search for `John` in every row in the table, and adjust the address

Now suppose a productname changes, again you have to search all rows and update

That is lots of work, very inefficient, and guaranteed to go wrong at some point

Now I only used 4 tables in this example, can you image what will happen if you would merge 20 tables into 1 ?

And the redundancy is not your only problem, what if you want to look at a client, what row should you use ?
What if you want to look at an order, what row should you use ?
What if you want to look at a product, what row should you use ?

In this one table design, you cannot identify a single row for customer, or order anymore. That is because each row contains everyting, there is no distinct row anymore for a customer, or a product, or an order...

Merging all tables into one big table is simply not possible to maintain

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you for your answers!

I am trying to integrate old ms sql db to new IDFLOW Software.
This software understand from ms sql db but only from one table but my old db contains 18 tables....
IDFLOW understand from views, but it is not good to work with views, they are okay for card design in IDFLOW, but views are not okay  to write new data in db from IDFLOW interface , because in views it is not possible to write new data in db!

And now I started to think to create one db with one table with all columns, and I completed it successfully!
Now in my sql server I am with two db, old db and new db.
Now I don't know how to export data from old db and import it to new db?
I am talking about export column2 from table1 from db1 and import it in column2 from table1 from db2 ....
and so and so ........... column2 from table2  from db1 and import it in column3 from table1 from db2 ............
 and so and so .... column 5 from table18 from db1 and import it in column10 form table1 from db2.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, but IDFLOW works only with one table...

And I asked Jolly and they say utilize your DB for one table.

IDFLOW is a software for ID CARDS .

I think it is possible to use one db with one table and all columns for employee information.

The goal is.. in IDFLOW enter all data for new employee, when you enter data from IDFLOW interface they go into MS SQL DB and all fields from DB are in card design configured, and when you select records for one employee from IDFLOW interface (from db) you can print ID CARD with all data for employee.

The question is how to migrate old records from old db in new.

It is not big database, it is only 6 GB from 2006.
And we  use it only for printing id cards.